# Interpretation of SVM accuracy

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I use "LIBSVM" library for classification.

If my first class is the same as the second class, for accuracy I will get 50% or 0%.

What does it mean to get 30% or 20% of precision?

Comment: I still fail to understand the experiment you are doing. What do you mean by "the first class is the same as the second class"? If they are same, they should be in one class? From your comment to Harald's answer, ("I ask two subjects to the same movement"), I guess that you have 2 samples from one class. You should at least ask those 2 subjects to make a different movement, then you will have 4 samples from 2 classes. And I don't know what type of features you are using but a dataset of 2 samples is definitely very small.

Comment: it is our experience,  we want to see the resulat between 2 subjects make the same mouvement

Comment: So you are trying to identify people based on their movement patterns? If so, i guess you are right, your classes are the people. In this case, reporting the classification accuracy can make more sense though. Are you sure you need to measure the precision, but not the classification accuracy?

Comment: please can you see me what is the difference between, precision and classification accuracy

Comment: if the problem was image retrieval with classes car, human and boat, and the test image was infact a car image, then your precision would be (the number of car images you returned)/(number of car images in your database). there is also another measure called recall, both are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

Comment: when i use !Libsvm, i obtain Accuracy = 50.7937% (64/126) (classification), What does it mean ?!it is a good classifier or it s just classifier by chance

Comment: it means it classified 64 of the 126 samples (again, what are they? and what do their labels mean?) correctly. If this is binary classification, then yes the accuracy is very close to random decision.

Answer (score 1):

A [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) is a binary classifier. That means, you can distinguish only 2 classes.

If both classes are the same, classification doesn't make sense.

If you have more then 2 classes you need to use different classification methods, such as k-means or neural networks. However, multi-class classification with SVM can still be done by reducing the multi-class decision problem to [multiple binary classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Multiclass_SVM).

Comment: my experience is, I take two set of data generated by two subject that do the same thing,  I get almost the Same data,

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more detailed?

Comment: I classify the movements, I ask two subjects to the same movement.
I get almost the same data, what does it mean to get 50%  of accuracy

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you if you explain yourself this scarce.

Comment: I  want just to understand the meaning of obtaining 50% of preccision with SVM

Comment: Generally, [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_binary_classification) is the ratio of true positives over all positives. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: if i have 2 classes that loke the same, i should obtain 50% or 0% of accuracy

Comment: Precision measures the quality of a classifier by comparing the predictions $Y$ with of the ground truth (i.e true Class $X$). Accuracy is a different metric for a classifier. However, both don't tell you anything about the class distribution, nor how similar the classes are.

Comment: I know but we can guess it, if you have two very different classes Normally the precission will be great.

Comment: Again, can you reformulate your question a little more detailed? What are you interested in?

Comment: my question is easy, how to interpret the precession of svm ?, if you have two classes that look like, the result of 50% is like classification by chance, is  it  right or not

Comment: No its not right. It depends on the class distribution in your data. If 80% of your data is Class $A$ and only 20% Class $B$, your precision is widely different to a distribution with 40% $A$ and 60%$B$. You can't compare data by accuracy or precision. Both values are used to compare classifiers.

Comment: I  take 50% for the first class and 50 % from the second, and i obtain 50% of accuracy

Comment: Accuracy then means that the classifier manages to correctly predict the Class in 50% of the samples **of this one dataset**. Generally precision is different from accuracy!